# How to Convert from a Residual Number System to a Mixed Radix System?

Tags: math, numbers, modular-arithmetic, mixed-radix

I understand the concept of a [Residual Number System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_number_system) and the concept of a [Mixed Radix system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix), but I'm having difficulty getting any of the conversion methods I find to work in a simple case study.

I started at Knuth's Art of Computer Programming but that had a bit too much on the theory of the conversion, and once Euler was mentioned I was lost. Wikipedia has a [nice section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_number_system#Associated_mixed_radix_system) on the subject, which I tried [here](http://mathbin.net/163024) and [here](http://mathbin.net/163082) but both times I couldn't get back to the number where I started.

I found a good article [here (PDF)](http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~cf/M2/wei.pdf), which I condensed the relevant sections [here](http://mathbin.net/163080), but I don't understand the multiplicative inverses and their notation. Specifically, how y_2 = |(3 - 19)|(1/31)|_7|_7 = |5 * 5|_7 Especially how |1/31|_7 = 5

Comment: I'm not certain the Wikipedia article is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, I read the Talk page on the Residual Number System page, and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) will be worth reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplicative inverses are to be taken with respect to a modulus (here 7). Since the modulus 7 is prime, every number (modulo 7) has an inverse. In particular, 31_7 = 3_7 (since 31 = 4*7 +3 - sorry if I'm too didactic), and its inverse is 5 because 3 * 5 = 15 = 1_7. So we can write
    |1/31|_7 = 5.

Now

```
y_2 = |(3 - 19) |(1/31)|_7 |_7
    = | (-16) * 5 |_7
    = | 5 * 5 |_7            since -16 = (-3)*7 + 5
    = 4
```

Comment: I now understand how you get |-16|_7 = 5, that's an unusual way of handling negative modulus in my experience, but I can work with that. I'm still lost on this |(1/31)|_7 = 5 business. I understand that |31|_7 = |3|_7, but I'm not following you on the inverse. 3 * 5 = 15, but |15|_7 = 0.

Comment: ahem... 15 = 2*7 + 1, therefore |15|_7 =1.